# how to get values in array in javascript

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript

```
DATA = {
    SKILLS :  [
        { NAME: "React", LEVEL: "75" },
        { NAME: "sfdc", LEVEL: "80" },
        { NAME: "Salesforce", LEVEL: "50"},
        { NAME: "html", LEVEL: "95" },
        { NAME: "css", LEVEL: "98" }
    ]
}
```

how can i get LEVEL  values in for loop in javascript

i am not able to get level values in loop

```
        callMe() {
         console.log('Im inside')
              console.log(JSON.stringify(this.DATA.SKILLS))
      for(var i=0;i<this.DATA.size();i++) {
       console.log("details>>"+this.DATA.SKIILS.LEVEL);
       }
   }
```

Comment: maybe this can help you: [working with objects in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATA` is an object, not an array, so it lacks `size()` method, therefore `this.DATA.size()` will throw an error, something like "DATA.size is not a function".

`DATA.SKILLS` is an array, so you have to loop over this property.
If you want to simply print the levels you could use a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
for (const skill of this.DATA.SKILLS) {
    console.log('level:', skill.LEVEL);
}
```

If you want to collect the levels in a new array you could leverage [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
const levels = this.DATA.SKILLS.map((skill) => skill.LEVEL);
console.log('levels list:', levels);
```

Comment: thanks @rubenDG. it worked